# Link from Dashboard to Discovery view

Tags: kibana

When looking at a dashboard, I would like a way to quickly view all of the log entries related to a given data set.

Currently, I drill into a panel/lens, gather the query and filters, open a new Discover tab, and rebuild the search. There must be a better way, and I must not be the alone in wanting to do this.

Comment: You can embed a search into a dashboard. If the search does not have filters or queries, it will show all the data in a index pattern; the filters/queries on the dashboard will apply also on the embedded search.

Comment: Thanks @dcolazin, I really appreciate your help, but this is not the feature I was hoping to find. (I realize this stack-overflow, not Kibana feature-request page ;-)) I don't want to see the search results on the dashboard: I want the ability to right-click and open the search-results corresponding to queries in a panel/lens. I don't want to have to write the search in two different places.

Comment: ahh, yes, I understood your question wrongly. I don't think there is such feature right now. Maybe it is worth asking for it on github